# Failure to read a custom object from Firestore--why?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, runtime-error

I get this error message

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type java.util.ArrayList to String (found in field 'allNames')

when I am trying to read a document from Firestore into a custom object DBStructure.class.

Here is the code I am using to retrieve the data:

```
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private DocumentReference DBStructureDocRef = db.document(DB_STRUCTURE_PATH);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRoom = new Room();
        mDBStructure = new DBStructure();

        readData();
        HandleSpinnerSelection("", -1);
    }

    private void readData() {
        DBStructureDocRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                            **mDBStructure = documentSnapshot.toObject(DBStructure.class)**;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Here is the DBStructure.class.

```
    public class DBStructure {

    List<String> allTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> allSurfaces = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Map<String, Unit>> hospitalLayout = new HashMap<>();

    public DBStructure() {
    }

    public DBStructure(String allTypes, String allNames, List<String> allSurfaces, Map<String, Map<String, Unit>> hospitalLayout) {
        setAllTypes(allTypes);
        setAllNames(allNames);
        setAllSurfaces(allSurfaces);
        this.hospitalLayout = hospitalLayout;
    }

    public List<String> getAllTypes() {
        return allTypes;
    }

    public void setAllTypes(String newType) {
        allTypes.add(newType);
    }

    public List<String> getAllNames() {
        return allNames;
    }

    public void setAllNames(String newName) {
        allNames.add(newName);
    }

    public List<String> getAllSurfaces(){
        return allSurfaces;
    }
    public void setAllSurfaces(List<String> surfaces) {
        // Ugly but easy gymnastics to avoid duplicates
        HashSet<String> allSurfacesSet = new HashSet<>(this.allSurfaces);
        for (String surface : surfaces)
            allSurfacesSet.add(surface);
        List<String> allSurfaces = new ArrayList<>(allSurfacesSet);
        this.allSurfaces = allSurfaces;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, Unit>> getHospitalLayout() {
        return hospitalLayout;
    }

    public void setHospitalLayout(String unitType, String unitName, long first, long last, List<String> surfaces) {
        Map<String, Map<String, Unit>> hospitalLayout = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Unit> nameRoomsSurfaces = new HashMap<>();
        Unit roomsSurfaces = new Unit();
        roomsSurfaces.setUnit(first, last, surfaces);
        nameRoomsSurfaces.put(unitName, roomsSurfaces);
        hospitalLayout.put(unitType, nameRoomsSurfaces);
        this.hospitalLayout = hospitalLayout;

        setAllTypes(unitType);
        setAllNames(unitName);
        setAllSurfaces(surfaces);
    }

    public Map<String, Unit> getUnitNamesRoomsSurfaces(String type, Map<String, Map<String, Unit>> hospitalLayout){
        // Extracts the namesRoomsSurfaces from the HospitalLayout using the passed Type
        Map<String, Map<String, Unit>> layout = hospitalLayout;
        Map<String, Unit> namesRoomsSurfaces = layout.get(type);
        return namesRoomsSurfaces;
    }

    public Unit getRoomsSurfaces (String name, Map<String, Unit> nameRoomsSurfaces){
        return nameRoomsSurfaces.get(name);
    }
}
```

(Unit is a second class that seemed to be necessary to have both integer and List values under the same parent key in the DBStructure HashMap).

```
    public class Unit {
    // Defines the unit Name-Rooms-Surfaces
    Long firstRoom;
    Long lastRoom;
    List<String> surfaceList = new ArrayList<>();
    //Unit mUnit = new Unit();

    public Unit() {
    }


    public void setUnit (long firstRoom, long lastRoom, List<String> surfaceList) {
        this.firstRoom = firstRoom;
        this.lastRoom = lastRoom;
        this.surfaceList = surfaceList;
    }

    public Long getFirstRoom() {
        return firstRoom;
    }

    public Long getLastRoom() {
        return lastRoom;
    }

    public List<String> getSurfaceList() {
        return surfaceList;
    }

}
```

...and finally, here is what the data looks like in Firestore, written there by a simple .set(mDBStructure)

[image: Data set with three lists and one nested hashmap]

I thank anyone who out of sheer altruism takes the time to read through this spaghetti code.

Comment: What is the value of `DB_STRUCTURE_PATH` ?

Comment: The path works:  afterall, the data got into firestore using the path to .set(mDBStrucure)....And additionally, the error message references the first field in the document:  allNames.                               public static final String DB_STRUCTURE_PATH = "DBStructureCollection/DBStructureDoc";

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to specifically indicate which field you are deserializing.
For example in your case, inside onSuccess

```
DocumentSnapshot document = documentSnapshot.getResult();
DbStructure db = new DbStructure();
db.setAllNames((List<String>) document.get("allNames"));
db.setAllTypes((List<String>) document.get("allTypes"));`
```

and so on. In that case When deserializing your returning objects, there wont be conflict. By the way in your setters, you have to change the parameter into List type))).

I did not test it, I hope it works))

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  To specifically indicate which field I am deserializing would preclude me from directly reading the data into an object, and instead have to resort to the...I think I have heard it referred to as "atomistic" or something like that, while the firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) shows an example where a custom object that includes a List is read directly into a variable of that class.

Comment: But speaking of this, I think you are on to something when you speak of my parameters, needing to change them, that sounds right to me.  But from what I understand, List is an interface, and ArrayList is a class...could you please give me more specifics of what change you are suggesting?  Thank you.

Comment: In your big POJO class, when you are setting the values, you add the value to the list by String. I would suggest when getting the reference from firebase you will have the List<String> object, in your setter, allNames = firebaseReturnedList, to change the reference.

Comment: --you were ABSOLUTELY right!  It took some ugliness further down in the program, to take a string and add it to a local List<String>, then pass it into the setter, then addAll()--but it makes perfect sense to me now.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, Glad it helped you. Could you accept my answer?)))